# Where can I find a JDK for 32 bit Windows?

Tags: java, 32-bit

For the life of me I can't seem to find a working version of the Java SE JDK for a 32 bit Windows machine.  Where did oracle put it?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: What version of the JDK?  5?  6?  7?

Comment: Every Sun/Oracle version and update is available here from Java 1.1 to Java 8 EA http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Eh, for what is the down vote?

Comment: It's downvoted because some SO users would rather do that than help out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go on the Oracle website - the thing you are looking for is x86, not x32.

You can pick whichever version of Java you need. The newest one is Java 7, but keep in mind that a lot of people are still using Java 6.

I think it is an important skill (especially if you plan to do serious work with Java) to know how to maneuver in the Oracle website (and documentation) because you will be using it a lot. Try to avoid Google, and other mirror websites, it's always the safest to take things from the source.

Comment: Ok, I was confused about x86 = 32-bit.  Thank you.

Comment: In 2020, new question for jdk 14 opened at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436626/java-development-kit-jdk-14-32bit-x86-for-windows-10-download-link-needed/62436627#62436627

Answer (score 2):

For JDK 7,

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html

You will just need to select the `Windows x86`, which the file name is: jdk-7-windows-i586.exe

For JDK 6u38 (the latest),

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u38-downloads-1877406.html

You will just need to select the `Windows x86`, which the file name is: jdk-6u38-windows-i586.exe

Answer (score 1):

Here!

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The provided link has version 6 and 7 :)

Comment: Bad suggestion.  Java 7 is stable too.  Java 6 is approaching EOL.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here:

Google "JDK" > [First result](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) > Click 'download' for JDK > Download Windows x86 version (currently jdk-7u10-windows-i586.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Visit CNET:http://download.cnet.com/Java-Development-Kit-32-bit/3000-2218_4-12091.html

I hope I am right. Or search the CNET

Comment: I wouldn't recommend downloading JDK (or any other open source software from Oracle) from any other place than the Oracle website itself ...